# Cannot send text/plain as in multipart email

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email

This is not working to send a text and html multipart email? However, the user sees no text/plain part in gmail?

```
Dim M As New Net.Mail.MailMessage("someemail@domain.net", Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("Emailvalidation"))
        M.To.Clear()
        M.To.Add(New Net.Mail.MailAddress(TargetEmail, TargetName))
        Select Case SA.Address.Province
            Case "BC"
                M.Bcc.Add(New Net.Mail.MailAddress("bobs email", "bob"))
        End Select
        M.Subject = Subject

        Dim AV2 = Net.Mail.AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(M2.Body, New Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html"))
        M.AlternateViews.Add(AV2)

        Dim PT As String = PlainTextTemplate
        Dim AV = Net.Mail.AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(PT, New Net.Mime.ContentType("text/plain"))
        M.AlternateViews.Add(AV)
```

Answer (score 0):

We figured it out... The code actually works. Gmail users only need to toggle "Message text garbled?" to have gmail show the plain text version.